# Circle wont change colors when my mouse is over it

Tags: python, math, pygame

I'm trying to use math.hypo(x1 - x2)(y1 - y2) to detect if my mouse coordinates are over my circle. After some debugging of general problems I cant figure out what is wrong with it. Here is the code I believe to be relevant. I'm brand new to this besides a few hours of webdev on codeacademy so sorry for any weird coding.

```
    # bubble and mouse stuff
orange = (255, 165, 0)
dark_orange = (255, 140, 0)
bubble_x = 300
bubble_y = 400
bubble_pos = (bubble_x, bubble_y)
bubble_rad = 100


def mouse_pos():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            mouse_coords = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            print(mouse_coords)
            mouse_x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
            mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]




def bubble():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        mouse_x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
        mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]
    else:
        mouse_x = 0
        mouse_y = 0
    bubble_color = dark_orange
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, bubble_color, bubble_pos, bubble_rad)
    distance = math.hypot(bubble_x - mouse_x, bubble_y - mouse_y)
    if distance >= bubble_rad:
        bubble_color = orange


# Game Loop
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                Kill_counter += 1
    GraveImg = pygame.transform.scale(GraveImg, (150, 150))
    grave()
    show_counter(Kill_counterX, Kill_counterY)
    mouse_pos()
    bubble()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `bubble_color`, before the circle is drawn. Further, I recommend to get the current mouse position by [`pygame.mouse.get_pos()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html)

```py
def bubble():
    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    # set the current color
    bubble_color = dark_orange
    distance = math.hypot(bubble_x - mouse_x, bubble_y - mouse_y)
    if distance >= bubble_rad:
        bubble_color = orange

    # draw the circle with the current color 
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, bubble_color, bubble_pos, bubble_rad)
```

---

I strongly recommend to use just one event loop. Handle the event in the main application loop. Note, [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) removes the events from the queue, thus the 1st event loop will get the events, but the 2nd loop will miss them.
Delete the function `mouse_pos`, it does not do what you expect it to do.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working as intended now.